# Avoid an Android app enter in onPause() state

Tags: android, augmented-reality, lifecycle, onpause

I'm programming an Android app that use arToolkit for AR Tags analyse (obtaining the device position using AR tags). The main activity extends to `andARActivity` who extends to `Activity`, so I can't make it a `Service`.

I'm trying to make the AR app run in background while an other app is running (using the data from the first app). The problems is that if I press the HOME button, the BACK button or I force a second execution from eclipse, it launch the  `onPause()` metod from the Activity class. That metod make the execution pause and the app stop all their processes.

I've tried to implement a `onPause()` method who avoid the execution of the Activity `onPause()`. Normally, if in `the mainActivity` `onPause()` method I don't call the `super.onPause()`, and that method doesn't do anything, it would exit to the home screen while running the app, but it stop and exit.

Anybody know how can I make the app run without pausing or using a Service class?

Thanks!

Comment: You can't. Or if there IS some way of doing so, you SHOULDN'T. Any background processing should be running in a Service.

Answer (score 1):

The best way is native module in C. Threads, sockets etc. - all running all of the time.

Comment: I have android app with native modules in C. In Java part of this app run GpsReceiver and SmsReceiver. OnPause() stops only UI, but receivers still send events to the running C native part with threads, timers, sockets and file IO.